# Is there a way to modify this YouTube download script to access the 4K version of the video?

Tags: python, python-2.7, youtube

I've been using the script below to download technical videos for later analysis. The script has worked well for me and retrieves the highest resolution version available for the videos that I have needed.

Now I've come across a [4K YouTube video](https://youtu.be/vzS1Vkpsi5k), and my script only saves an mp4 with 1280x720.

I'd like to know if there is a way to adjust my current script to download higher resolution versions of this video. I understand there are python packages that might address this, but right now I would like stick to this step-by-step method if possible.

[image]  [image]

**above:** info from Quicktime and OSX

```
"""
length:   175 seconds
quality:  hd720
type:     video/mp4; codecs="avc1.64001F, mp4a.40.2"
Last-Modified: Sun, 21 Aug 2016 10:41:48 GMT
Content-Type: video/mp4
Date: Sat, 01 Apr 2017 16:50:16 GMT
Expires: Sat, 01 Apr 2017 16:50:16 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=21294
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 35933033
Connection: close
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Server: gvs 1.
"""

import urlparse, urllib2

vid        = "vzS1Vkpsi5k"
save_title = "YouTube SpaceX - Booster Number 4 - Thaicom 8 06-06-2016"
url_init   = "https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=" + vid

resp = urllib2.urlopen(url_init, timeout=10)
data = resp.read()
info =  urlparse.parse_qs(data)
title = info['title']

print "length:  ", info['length_seconds'][0] + " seconds"

stream_map   = info['url_encoded_fmt_stream_map'][0]
vid_info     = stream_map.split(",")

mp4_filename = save_title + ".mp4"

for video in vid_info:
    item = urlparse.parse_qs(video)

    print 'quality: ', item['quality'][0]
    print 'type:    ', item['type'][0]

    url_download  = item['url'][0]
    resp          = urllib2.urlopen(url_download)

    print resp.headers

    length  = int(resp.headers['Content-Length'])
    my_file = open(mp4_filename, "w+")

    done, i = 0, 0
    buff    = resp.read(1024)        
    while buff:

        my_file.write(buff)
        done += 1024
        percent = done * 100.0 / length
        buff = resp.read(1024)

        if not i%1000:                
            percent = done * 100.0 / length
            print str(percent) + "%"

        i += 1
    break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I have not taken the time to get to the bottom of this. However, I did find that when you do:

`stream_map   = info['url_encoded_fmt_stream_map'][0]`

Somehow you only get a selection of a single 720p option, one 'medium' and two 'small'.

However, if you change that line into:

`stream_map   = info['adaptive_fmts'][0]`

you will get all the available versions, including the `2160p`  one. Thus, the 4K one.

PS: You'd have to comment out the `print quality` and `print type` command since those labels aren't always available in the new throughput. When commenting them out however, and adapting your script as explained above, I was able to successfully download the 4K version.

Comment: It's certainly taking 4x more time to download, looks like we've got a winner!

Comment: Great! In that case you could probably mark it as solved ;-)

Comment: Definitely - I'm still struggling with the download speed using my phone's 4G, I was just waiting to post an "It works!" comment along with the acceptance, so I left you a message about download speed to let you know I was working on it...

Comment: Ah, well, sorry for the impatience over here, misread your first comment ;)

Comment: It works - perfectly! Thank you for the speedy reply. This is exactly the solution I needed.

Comment: Glad I was able to help!

Comment: I've just [linked to your answer](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/20922/#comment56808_20923).

Answer (score 1):

indeed
info ['adaptive_fmts'] [0]
returns the information of the whole video, but the url is not usable directly , but the bar of advancement

Comment: I think you might be adding some helpful information, but I don't understand what you are saying. Can you use two or three sentences and explain more fully? Thank you!

Comment: URLs what we can extract from "info ['adaptive_fmts'] [0]" are not links to stream what can directly be used, for example in a download, but they are links to pages with a player as this:

Comment: Oh I see what you mean I think. I'll do some more reading on it. You can see I'm using a script without really understanding why it works. Thanks!

Comment: https://r6---sn-hpa7znse.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?gir=yes&sparams=clen,dur,ei,gir,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,keepalive,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,requiressl,source,expire&lmt=1492456122283931&ei=vCg6WZzSG8WmWMidivgG&requiressl=yes&ip=93.42.2.11&mime=video/mp4&source=youtube&mm=31&mn=sn-hpa7znse&pl=16&id=o-ANSU6MyuZGV5Fdlky1CFSrWJlppVY-uCahOD6POgXuIP&ipbits=0&ms=au&mt=1496983536&mv=m&expire=1497005340&key=yt6&keepalive=yes&clen=306175165&itag=264&initcwndbps=916250&dur=253.360&signature=277C49AF2A4C463A91B26A81142528FD36A9C710.6C4D6237BDE97025FC30A76FFAC7542FC25DF2C1

Comment: Also I am interested to extract all the links, perhaps some operation on the link is necessary for making it downloadable.
Does someone know how to do?

Comment: The [stackexchange newtork of sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) in general, and stackoverflow here are great places to learn! They have a fairly rigid structure for asking and answering questions though. You can ask a new question here, but it needs to be fairly specific. "does someone know how to..." would be quickly closed. If you look at my question here, I've posted a very specific problem and included all of the work that I've done first. Only after that can I expect to get an answer here. It's just the way this site works. A good start; [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).